# Can I prevent VS Code from suggesting HTML Emmet Abbreviations when I start writing the abbreviation with non-lowercase letters?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

Why does Emmet try abbreviate words starting with Capital letters even though they are not components nor valid html tag?
I find the abbreviations useful for jsx related tasks but it also tries to abbreviate anything that is a capital letter. This make it frustrating to use when trying to fill in multiple div tags.

This issue is related to [text](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33028) but I couldn't solve it by using

```json
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
  "html": {
    "tag_case": "lower"
  }
}
```

I don't want to turn the abbreviations off as they are mostly useful.
Any ideas?

Tried :

```json
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
  "html": {
    "tag_case": "lower"
  }
}
```

and adjusting the settings on emmet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is the call to [`makeSnippetSuggestion`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-emmet-helper/blob/ea184b3b7d6d7ffbc1721b5ce986c8477d420127/src/emmetHelper.ts#L224) in [`@vscode/emmet-helper`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vscode/emmet-helper). That call is made within [`doComplete`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-emmet-helper/blob/ea184b3b7d6d7ffbc1721b5ce986c8477d420127/src/emmetHelper.ts#L63) [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-emmet-helper/blob/ea184b3b7d6d7ffbc1721b5ce986c8477d420127/src/emmetHelper.ts#L196)- especially pay attention to the part that does `const currentAbbr = abbreviation + snippetKey.substr(prefix.length);`. TL;DR I don't see a way at the time of this writing to prevent this from happening. If you want to be able to do that, then you should raise an issue ticket.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Comment: That is quite annoying. I might raise a ticket on this in future but thanks for your response.